# Typescript Winston Compile Errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, winston

I want to use winston to log errors in a NodeJS application that uses TypeScript. But whenever I import Winston into a Typescript script I get the same eleven errors:

```
node_modules/winston-transport/index.d.ts:6:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

6 /// <reference types="node" />
                        ~~~~

node_modules/winston-transport/index.d.ts:8:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

8 import * as stream from 'stream';
                          ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/index.d.ts:4:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

4 /// <reference types="node" />
                        ~~~~

node_modules/winston/index.d.ts:6:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

6 import * as NodeJSStream from "stream";
                                ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/index.d.ts:121:28 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

121     stream(options?: any): NodeJS.ReadableStream;
                               ~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/index.d.ts:165:34 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

165   let stream: (options?: any) => NodeJS.ReadableStream;
                                     ~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/lib/winston/config/index.d.ts:4:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

4 /// <reference types="node" />
                        ~~~~

node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/index.d.ts:4:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

4 /// <reference types="node" />
                        ~~~~

node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/index.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'.

6 import {Agent} from "http";
                      ~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/index.d.ts:31:14 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

31     stream?: NodeJS.WritableStream;
                ~~~~~~

node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/index.d.ts:77:13 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

77     stream: NodeJS.WritableStream;
               ~~~~~~
```

I have only added the regular winston as dependency, not @types/winston (I've tried it with that package, but it did not help).

I import winston by using `import * as winston from 'winston'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that winston also requires @types/node in TypeScript. As soon as I added it as dependency (`npm i @types/node`) it worked!